# RecyclerView not updating the view or not calling the onCreate view holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that does not update the text inside the items of the recyclerview.

When initializing the Recycler view, everything is fine. But when you call the filter method. It gives you the correct item as per the catlog. The correct position for the item. The Correct number of items in the ArrayList. But even the image is getting update by picasso. But it does not update the textview that I have on OnBind from the RecyclerView.

```
public class HospitalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HospitalAdapter.HospitalViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Hospital> hospitalList;
private ArrayList<Hospital> originalList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

private StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


//View FIELDS
private TextView HospitalName;
private TextView Phone;
private RatingBar Rating;
private ImageView Image;
private TextView Location;
private TextView Address;
private LinearLayout cardView;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;


public HospitalAdapter(Context context, Activity activity,String category,String search, ArrayList<Hospital> hospitalArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    hospitalList = hospitalArrayList;


}



@NonNull
@Override
public HospitalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hospital_list_item,parent,false);
    HospitalViewHolder holder = new HospitalViewHolder(view);
    Log.e("Holder","On CreateViewHolder getting called");
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  HospitalViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Hospital hospital = hospitalList.get(position);

    HospitalViewHolder tempHolder = holder;

    HospitalName.setText(hospital.getName());
    Phone.setText(hospital.getContactNumber());
    Rating.setRating(hospital.getRating());
    Location.setText(hospital.getLocation());
    Address.setText(hospital.getAddress());
    final DatabaseReference dbrate = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();





}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return hospitalList.size();
}


public class HospitalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public HospitalViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        HospitalName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_Name);
        Phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_phone);
        Rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_rating);
        Image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_imageview);
        Address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_address);
        Location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_city);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_cardview);

    }
}

private void sharedElementTransition(View view,Uri uri,Hospital hospital){
    Pair[] pair = new Pair[5];
    pair[0] = new Pair<View,String>(view.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_imageview),"hospital_image");
    pair[1] = new Pair<View,String>(view.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_rating),"hospital_rating");
    pair[2] = new Pair<View,String>(view.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_cardview),"hospital_cardview");
    pair[3] = new Pair<View,String>(view.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_Name),"hospital_name");
    pair[4] = new Pair<View,String>(view.findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_item_phone),"hospita_contact");
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,pair);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, HospitalTabbed.class);


    i.putExtra("THE_URI",uri.toString());
    i.putExtra("Key",hospital.getKey());
    i.putExtra("Details",hospital.getDetails());
    i.putExtra("Rating",hospital.getRating());
    i.putExtra("CityName",hospital.getLocation());
    i.putExtra("Contact",hospital.getContactNumber());
    i.putExtra("Address",hospital.getAddress());
    i.putExtra("Name",hospital.getName());
    context.startActivity(i,options.toBundle());
}



public void filterList(ArrayList<Hospital> filteredList){
    hospitalList = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

this is my RecyclerView. Now I am wondering if there could be a problem on the my Layout file. Since the recycler sometimes acts differently on different layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/lobby_spinner_category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lobby_search_edit_text"

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/lobby_search_btn"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.27"
                    android:text="search"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/lobby_speech"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.13"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lobby_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"


     />



</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/lobby_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_assignment_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/lobby_bottom_appbar"/>

<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/lobby_bottom_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mtrl_bottomappbar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:transitionName="lobby_constraint"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
    app:fabAttached="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lobby_recycler_view"
    app:menu="@menu/lobby_bar_menu">

</android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Summary of the problem. The list items textview is not getting updated. But the onclick when going to another activity is fine. The image is being updated by picasso is fine and catlog information about the item is also correct. It is just when filtering the Textview does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I need to make the changes in the older's fields not on the adapters field.

OnBindViewHolder

```
    holder.HospitalName.setText(hospital.getName());
    holder.Phone.setText(hospital.getContactNumber());
    holder.Rating.setRating(hospital.getRating());
    holder.Location.setText(hospital.getLocation());
    holder.Address.setText(hospital.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several probabilities : 
1. You need to setLayoutManager to the RecyclerView
2. You need to set your adapter to your Recyclerview
3. You need to make sure your getItemCount is not 0

Comment: I already fixed it. But yes, 3 of those things are a possibilities. But that is not the problem. Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

all

```
private TextView HospitalName;
private TextView Phone;
private TextView Location;
private TextView Address;
```

not updated?